# php exec how to calculate time?

Tags: php, exec

I'm trying to implement some kind of 'multiprocessing' in php for my task. The task is to check the status of every device in our network.

For that i decided to use looped `exec` and it works. But i don't know whether it works fine or not:

```
$command = "php scan_part.php $i > null &";
exec($command);
```

This calls `scan_part.php` as many times as i need, but the question is: how can i calculate time needed for all of my `scan_part.php`'s to be executed?

Please, help me, i'm stuck!

Comment: Multithreading and multiprocessing are both valid approaches to parallelism (with different pros and cons) but are distinct. You should really call what you're doing 'multiprocessing' instead of 'multithreading', since PHP has absolutely no support for threading.

Comment: thanks, made a correction. any ideas about the question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`proc_open`](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.proc-open.php) to launch your script instead of `exec`. [`Proc_open`](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.proc-open.php) lets you wait until a process is done through [`proc_close`](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.proc-close.php), which waits until the termination of the program.

```
$starttime = microtime(true);
$processes = array();
// stdin, stdout, stderr- take no input, save no output
$descriptors = array(
    0 => array("file", "/dev/null", 'r'),
    1 => array("file", "/dev/null", 'w'),
    2 => array("file", "/dev/null", 'w'));

while ($your_condition)
{
    $command = "php scan_part.php $i"; // no pipe redirection, no background mark
    $processes[] = proc_open($command, $descriptors, $pipes);
}

// proc_close will block until the program terminates or will return immediately
// if the program has already terminated
foreach ($processes as $process)
    proc_close($process);
$endtime = microtime(true);

$delta = $endtime - $starttime;
```

Comment: i'll try this several hours later

Comment: great! this works. i had to make two corrections to your code: `$processes[] = proc_open($command, $descriptors, $pipes);` and `0 => array("file", "/dev/null", 'r'),...`

Comment: @k102 Oh, yeah, sorry. I couldn't test it where I was. I'll fix it in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the `microtime()` function. Example #2 on this page is useful:

```
http://php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php
```

**EDIT:** This approach will not work, because as pointed out in comments, the process is lauched in the background. I am unable to suggest a better approach.

Comment: i know this function, but how can i use it? my 'parent' script doesn't wait for it's children, and for this purpose they produce no output

Comment: The command is launched in background (notice the `&` at the end of `$command`), so all this will measure is the time it took to launch the processes.

Comment: According to the manual page for `exec()`, by passing the appropriate arguments you can get it to fill variables with the output and return value of the command issued. That to me suggested that `exec()` must wait until the command completes before it returns, rather than starting a process and then leaving it to run. But perhaps I am mistaken? Or perhaps your "child" script creates processes itself? It is not clear to me how your script operates.

Comment: @zneak: Then my answer does not solve the problem. I am afraid that I am unable to suggest a better approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can't request the time to execute on a normal operating system (it's a system call and handled by the kernel). For this you need a real time os.

But you can calculate it by record for each instance how much time it took to launch. Than calculate the average on that dataset.

microtime can give you the current time. Do this like so:

```
while(/** list proc */)
{
$starttime = microtime();
proc_open( /** some syntax here */);
$endtime = microtime() - $starttime;
//store time here
}
```

Comment: The programs won't run in parallel.

Comment: First sentence says "I'm trying to implement some kind of 'multiprocessing' in php for my task.". Wouldn't suggesting to make everything serial again defeat this purpose?

Comment: The question was, "how can i calculate time needed for all of my `scan_part.php`'s to be executed?" The time to fork is just a part of this answer: OP wants to know the total execution time, not just how much time it took to spawn the processes (and for control to be given back to the script). With `proc_open` without `proc_close`, you still do not achieve this goal.

Answer (score 1):

Does the `scan_part.php` script output anything that the calling script expects/accepts as input? If not, you can use `/usr/bin/time` to calculate the run time of the scan_part script:

```
exec('/usr/bin/time /usr/bin/php scan_part.php &');
```

That returns something like this:

```
0.00user 0.00system 0:00.00elapsed 0%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 4192maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+318minor)pagefaults 0swaps
```

which you can parse for the times. This would let you get execution time without having to modify scan_parts.

On the other hand, if scan_parts doesn't normally produce output, and you can/will modify it, then wrapping the contents of scan_parts with a couple `microtime(true)` calls and outputting the difference would be simpler.

```
$start = microtime(true);
.... do the core of scan_parts here
echo microtime(true) - $start; // output the runtime here
exit();
```

This gives you a SINGLE time value to return, saving you the parseing overhead of the `/usr/bin/time` stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the microtime(), if you want to benchmark a whole application you may also look into XDebug, it will give you detailed reports on the performance of your application.

For windows the latest version of Wampserver comes packaged with XDebug and webgrind. For linux the installation is also quite simple.

See: http://code.google.com/p/webgrind/