# shell_exec - logging & outputting

Tags: php, linux, shell, exec

I am running multiple `shell_exec`, `process.php`'s run in the background

On the `shell/ssh`, I execute the code like this: `username [~/public_html/curl]# php index.php`

Example....

**index.php**

```
<?php
 shell_exec("php process.php > /dev/null 2>&1 &");
 shell_exec("php process.php > /dev/null 2>&1 &");
 shell_exec("php process.php > /dev/null 2>&1 &");
 shell_exec("php process.php > /dev/null 2>&1 &");
?>
```

**process.php**

```
<?php
$section = rand(999,999999);
$z = 1;
print "STARTED .... \n";
while($z <= 10) {
 print "---------------------------------\n";
 print $section . ": " . $z . "\n";
 $z++;
 sleep(2);
}
print "LOOP FINISH at " . time();
?>
```

when `process.php`'s is running, I am having two problems with this:

1. I cant not see the output from `process.php`'s (I need to know what they are doing)
2. I need to know which process is finish and which have started.

What the best way logging the output in real time? saving into text file? or how can it be done to mysql database (logs table)?

Comment: try looking here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6252966/php-exec-how-to-calculate-time zneak advised me to use `proc_open`

Answer (score 2):

If your processes will be alive only within the lifetime of another php script, you could use popen instead of shell_exec:

http://us.php.net/popen

This gives you a very convenient way to get data from the other processes into your php script, using the same interface as file handles.  To know then the process is done, you could make sure the process sends an EOF (end-of-file) when it's done, and use the feof php function to detect it.

On the other hand, if your processes may live longer than any other php scripts that talk to it, then a text file may be a very practical solution.  Keep in mind, though, that disk access is always much much slower than memory access, so if you use text files for communication, it will not be optimally fast.

Comment: One process may take longer than other process..  (processes will be running 15 hours a day).  Processes must be executed at the same time.. (NOT when one process done and then do the next process). What do you think of this solution: for each process - it save output to the text file (eg: process_1.txt) - then I can open a txt file via brower (refresh it like every 5 seconds) ? I am looking for solution that I can view output/log for each process.

Comment: How good that solution is depends on your needs.  It sounds a little inelegant, but if it provides the functionality you need, then great.  There's always a trade-off between getting something working, and writing beautiful code.  It sounds like you're aiming to just get something working, which is totally fine.  If you get it working and find some things are slow, that's the time to look for a more elegant solution.

Comment: Tyler, I have came up with better solution. Instead saving into text files, I insert the log outcome into mysql database (logs table). In the log table, there is a field called process_id for getmypid() ...